# How to Optimize SQL Restore Performance with MySQL Dump

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, backup, mariadb-10.6

I'm currently working on a cron job that involves masking and modifying specific columns in a MariaDB 10.6 database. The process includes taking a dump of the production database using mysqldump and then applying it using the mysql command. Afterward, certain tables with sensitive data are updated. However, I'm encountering a significant issue related to the restore step, where the mysql restore command takes a substantial amount of time (around 2 hours) compared to the speedy 10-15 minutes it takes to produce the 35 GB dump.

Here are the commands I'm using:

the mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump -h ${sourceDbParams.host} -u ${sourceDbParams.user} --single-transaction --extended-insert --quick --disable-keys --set-charset -p${sourceDbParams.password} ${sourceDbParams.database} > /tmp/database_dump.sql
```

the mysql command:

```
mysql -h ${targetDbParams.host} -u ${targetDbParams.user} -p${targetDbParams.password} ${targetDbParams.database} < /tmp/database_dump.sql
```

Some context:

The production database is hosted on an AWS RDS instance with 16 vCPUs and 64GB of memory.
The masked database is on an AWS RDS instance with 8 vCPUs and 16GB of memory.
The cron job runs on an EC2 instance with 2 CPUs and 4GB of memory.
How can I improve the SQL restore performance for this process?

I've tried optimizing the mysqldump command with options like --opt. Any suggestions to make the mysql restore process more efficient and reduce the time it takes to complete the restore operation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a DMS job with custom value transformation to mask sensitive data, rather than the dump-and-restore method?

Comment: From the instance where you restore the mysqldump - Additional DB information request, please. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after RESTORE has been completed. C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for REDUCING restore time to complete.